# Continuity of a function between two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

What is the motivation behind the definition of continuity of a function between two topological spaces (i.e, $f : X \to Y$ is said to be continuous if $f^{-1}(v)$ is open for all open sets $v$ in $Y$)?

Comment: It's a generalization of continuity of functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

Comment: Alternately you want your morphism of sets to induce a morphism between the topologies, which is exactly what you are requiring the preimage operator to be. That is f: X —>Y is continuous if and only if the preimage function on Powersets restricts to a map between the topologies f^(-1): T_Y —> T_X

Comment: It is a very general idea to define structure preserving function in this manner. Think for example of measurable functions. A function is said to be measurable if the preimage of any measurable set is measurable. The reason to use the preimage comes also from the fact that preimages behave much more nicely with respect to set operations than images.

Answer (score 1):

Question concerning the *motivation* of something are often not easy to answer. Yes, the definition of continuity of $f$ by "preimages of open sets are open" is short and elegant, and this is what *good definitions* should be. But I am not sure whether it is optimal in a motivational sense.

In any textbook you will find various properties of a function $f : X \to Y$ which are equivalent to the continuity of $f$. One of these properties is

> For all $M \subset X$, $f(\overline M) \subset \overline{f(M)}$.

Here $\overline{\phantom X}$ denotes closure. In my opinion this explains very nicely what continuity means. Given a set $M \subset X$, the closure $\overline M$ is the set of all points of $X$ which can be arbitrarily closely approximated by points of $M$. Now consider $x \in \overline M$. Then $f(x)$ is contained in the closure $\overline{f(M)}$, i.e. can be arbitrarily closely approximated by points of $f(M)$. In other words, $f$ preserves the approximability relation and does not tear up something.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a comment to give details to the above comment of J. W. Tanner. You can prove easily the following:

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of topological spaces. The following are equivalent:

(i) For any open subset $V$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

(ii) For any $x\in X$, and any open subset $V$ of $Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open subset $U$ of $X$ containing $x$ such that $f(U)\subset V$ (continuity at $x$).