# Discussion of continuous functions in topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, definition

Here is the definition of continuous function that I like to go with even in topology:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be any topological spaces, let $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a function, and let $p$ be a point of $X$. Then $f$ is said to be *continuous at point $p$* if, for every open set $V$ of $Y$ such that $f(p) \in V$, there exists an open set $U$ of $X$ such that $p \in U$ and $f(U) \subset V$.

> Let $S$ be any subset of $X$. If the function $f$ in the preceding paragraph is continuous at every point $p \in S$, then $f$ is said to be *continuous on $S$*.

> Annd, if the function $f$ is continuous on $X$, then $f$ is simply said to be *continuous*.

Is my definition correct? I think satisfaction at every point of this is the definition that Munkres has shown to be equivalent to the definition of continuity in his Sec. 18.

Of course, I can show that the above definition of continuity at a point is equivalent to the one used for maps between metric spaces.

Is my approach consistent with that used in calculus and real or elementary complex analysis courses? If so, then why is it that the topology books mostly go with the definition of continuity requiring the inverse images of open sets being open?

What if we instead require that for a function $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ to be continuous at a point $p \in X$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ of $Y$ such that $f(p) \in V$? Are there any counter-examples of continuous-at-a-point real-valued functions of a real variable that fail to satisfy this condition?

PS:

Having read through the comments and the answer below, I would like to add the following to my original question:

If a function is continuous at some points of domain, it may still not be continuous on the whole domain, whereas the inverse image of open sets being open definition is that of continuity of a function on the whole domain. So is it not the more reasonable approach to first consider continuity at a point (just as in calculus and analysis courses) and then proceed to show that continuity on the whole domain occurs iff the inverse images of open sets in the co-domain space are open in the domain space?

Comment: "why is it that the topology books mostly go with the definition of continuity requiring the inverse images of open sets being open?" Maybe because it's simpler?

Comment: When I first started studying topology, I found the standard inverse images definition to be the easiest to work with. For instance it's pretty easy to show that  $$f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}V_i)=\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}(f^{-1}(V_i))$$  and $$f^{-1}(\bigcap\limits_{i \in I}V_i)=\bigcap\limits_{i \in I}(f^{-1}(V_i))$$
and with this you practically get basic properties of continuous maps for free.

Comment: @Surb But I think not false. You can take $U= f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: @SeraPhim Indeed, inverse images are better behaved than direct images.

Comment: @ε-δ: Indeed, but that's just adding a useless condition to a definition (so why adding it ?)

Comment: I agree. It is useless, but not wrong.

Comment: The first definition of continuity at a point you mention and its relation with global continuity are standard. I cannot quite refute the assertion of there being an universal stygma on them, but I refuse to believe it to be the case: it was taught to me, therefore it must be common knowledge. Whether or not in the economy of the proofs in a book one or the other fits, it might be a matter of taste of the author, or perhaps one is actually handier than the other.

Comment: For Bourbaki, a mapping $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if given any neighborhood $V'$ of $f(x_0)$ in $Y$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $x\in V$ implies $f(x)\in V'$. I struggle to see how this definition is (i) nonstandard (ii) more complicated than the "traditional" one.

Comment: @Surb: That condition is necessary, not useless: without that condition you could simply take $U=X$, and every function would be continuous at $p$. It is in fact the standard topological definition of continuity at a point.

Comment: Your definitions are standard and correct. There are many consequences of continuity that are actually equivalent to continuity, so any one of them could be the definition. Sometimes one of them is better for a given Q than another.

Answer (score 6):

I am accustomed to seeing both definitions in topology texts. Sometimes continuity at a point is defined first, perhaps because it’s the direct topological analogue of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition with which students are familiar from calculus. Sometimes global continuity is defined first, and while this is in large part a matter of pædagogical taste, I think that an even better case can be made for this approach: in general global continuity is more important and generally easier to work with. I would argue that in a purely topological setting global continuity is a more fundamental notion than continuity at a point. I’m not fond of category theory, but there’s a reason that continuous maps are the morphisms in the category of topological spaces.

At any rate, the textbooks that I have on hand (Kelley, Dugundji, Greever, Munkres (both editions), Willard, Nagata, Engelking) are roughly evenly divided between the two approaches.

For your last question, let

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
0,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;;
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous at $0$ and nowhere else. But for any $r>0$, $$f^{-1}\big[(-r,r)\big]=(-r,r)\cup(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\;,$$ which is not open in $\Bbb R$, so $f$ fails to satisfy your condition.

Comment: can we find a set $U$ for the function $f$ you've given as a counter-example such that $U$ is open in the domain space $\mathbb{R}$, $0 \in U$, and $U \subset f^{-1}\big( (-r, r) \big) = (-r, r) \cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood: No: $(-r,r)\cap\Bbb Q$ does not contain any non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: then how to show using the point-wise definition of continuity of maps between topological spaces that your map is indeed continuous at point $0$?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood: I’m sorry: I just noticed that I miswrote the description of $f^{-1}[(-r,r)]$, and that doubtless caused some confusion. In fact if $f[(-r,r)]\subseteq (-r,r)$, so $f$ is continuous at $0$. The problem is that $f^{-1}[(-r,r)]$ contains every irrational but only the rationals between $-r$ and $r$, so it’s not open.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is absolutely correct.

Your question comes very close to [Continuity of a function between two topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3754495). From a motivational (and historical) point of view I agree with you that *continuity at a point* is the basic concept.

This concept was introduced in the nineteenth century for functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in form of the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition, and it only works pointwise. In the beginning of the twentieth century the next level of abstraction was reached by introducing *metric spaces* as a generalization of the reals endowed with the usual distance-function $\lvert x - y \rvert$. Continuity is again defined pointwise via the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-approach. The final level of abstraction was the axiomatic definition of *topological spaces*, but I think at the beginning continuity was introduced again pointwise. See also [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a533/f6923bf44d9292a76299b7be14ae59ab6a1b.pdf).

Nevertheless, continuous functions are more interesting than non-continuous functions, and the most elegant definition of continuity is certainly that via  inverse images of open sets. This means that continuity is a global phenomenon, and individual points are not needed to describe it.